# Only show button when table row equals something

Tags: html, mysql, html-table

I have a table on my HTML page that gets results from my SQL database. I also have a delete button that lets you delete an animal from that table.

I only want Giraffes to be able to be deleted from my page so how do I get the delete button to only be shown on the animals that aren't Giraffes?

My table:

```
<form name="animals" method="post" action="animals.asp">
                <table border="1" id="animals">

                    <caption>Zoo Animals</caption>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Birth Date</th>
                        <th>Height</th>
                        <th>Food</th>
                        <th>Delete Animal</th>
                    </tr>
                    <% While Not objDBRS.EOF %>
                    <tr id=<%=objDBRS("AnimalID")%>>
                        <td><%=objDBRS("Name") %></td>
                        <td><%=objDBRS("BirthDate") %></td>
                        <td><%=objDBRS("Height") %></td>
                        <td><%=objDBRS("Food") %></td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="submit" name="Canceled" id="cancel" onclick="javascript:buttonCancel(<%=objDBRS("AnimalID")%>)">Cancel</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <%  objDBRS.MoveNext
            Wend%>
                </table>
                    <input type="hidden" id="AnimalID" name="AnimalID" />
                <br />
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?
if (!(strcmp(objDBRS("Name"),"Giraffe")))
  {
  echo "add the html for button here";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Is that PHP? I want to do this in either javascript or HTML

Comment: It is. everything within 
<? 
?>
is PHP.

Comment: Okay, do you know how to do it in either javascript or HTML?

Comment: yeah. you can set a cookie/session of the type of animal and then check that using javascript. Note: Storing confidential/important information in cookies are not advisable as they can be manipulated by the users.